# UIAlertView button to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.3, uialertview

I have two buttons for my `UIAlertView`. One of them goes back to `TableViewController` while another one have to go to another `ViewController`. The button that goes to the `TableViewController` can work. But the button that goes to the `ViewController` is showing me a blank view when I click the button.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    QuizTableViewController *quizTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"quizTable"];

    UINavigationController *quizController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:quizTable];
    [quizController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];

    [self presentViewController:quizController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    QuizAnsViewController *quizAns = [[QuizAnsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 

    [self presentViewController:quizAns animated:YES completion:nil];
}

}
```

The second part of the code is for the button to go another `ViewController`.

Anybody can help please? Thank you.

Comment: Does your other view controller have a nib file associated with it?  If so, what is its name?  After your presentViewController:quizAns line try logging quizAns.view to make sure it's not nil.

Comment: I inserted a Navigation Controller before the ViewController and now it is able to work already. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Story board so this might work

```
if (buttonIndex == 1){

   QuizAnsViewController *quizAns = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Identifier_of_that_view_controller"]; 
   [self presentViewController:quizAns animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you use NavigationController than I think this code is Solve your problem. You can Try.

```
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{

        QuizAnsViewController * quizAns = [[[QuizAnsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizAnsViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [self.navigationController quizAns animated:YES];

}
```